# Length of branches in forest (LaTex)

Tags: tikz-trees, forest, trees, branching

I've written this tree using the Forest package. The output is perfect, but I don't understand why in order to increase the length of the branch connecting r, I had to write [h, l=2] and not [r, l=2]. Thank you in advance

```
\documentclass[border=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\forestset{
  empty nodes/.style={
    for tree={calign=fixed edge angles},
    delay={
      where content={}{
        shape=coordinate,
        for current and siblings={anchor=north}
      }{}
    }
  },
}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
[$\Omega$, empty nodes
[F]
[($\alpha$), l=1.5[G][($\beta$)[B][($\gamma$)[r][h, l=2]]]]]]]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try with some like `[r, l*=2]` or  `[r, l*=2cm]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`l=2` really means `l=2pt`. In effect, `l` is irrelevant and `l sep` takes over. To see what it produces, remove `empty nodes` -- with `h, l=2` you get `r` directly below `h`, even though they are siblings.

Then `empty nodes` takes over and applies `calign=fixed edge angles`, pushing the nodes apart while keeping the `l`s intact.

So as Fran answered in the comment, `l*=2` on `r` does the trick, as this doubles the original `l`, pushing `r` below `h`.